# I finished AWS web service and test to enter domain web site and this error message popped up in chrome developer tool

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, api, vue.js, axios

this is the architecture used in AWS

how I configured AWS VPC

VPC’s private ip range : 172.31.0.0/16
1 public subnet
3 private subnets
how I configured AWS route table

private subnet route table configuration
->172.31.0.0/16 local
->0.0.0.0/0 NAT gateway
-included subnets
→ frontend private subnet / backend private subnet / RDS private subnet
total 3 private subnets included in private route table

public subnet route table
→ 172.31.0.0/16 local
→ 0.0.0.0/0 internet gateway
→ public subnet that contains Application Load Balancer / bastion host ec2 / NAT gateway
total 1 public subnet included in public route table

How I configured Application Load Balancer

internet facing
connected instance : frontend ec2 instance in private subnet
then all the configuration done

I entered domain web site to test it

then I confronted with this error

> [Vuetify] [UPGRADE] ‘v-content’ is deprecated, use ‘v-main’ instead.
> console.ts:34
>
> ***found in ***
>
> —> VMain
>
> *** VApp***
>
> *** App***
>
> *** Root***
>
> POST
> ‘http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/Product/item_list’
> xhr.js:177
>
> !net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED!
>
> !Uncaught (in promise) Error:Network Error createError.js:16
>
> *** at t.exports (createError.js:16)***
>
> *** at XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (xhr.js:84) !***
>
> POST
> ‘http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/Bag/bag_count’
> xhr.js:177
>
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error createError.js:16
>
> *** at t.exports (createError.js:16)***
>
> *** at XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (xhr.js:84)***

my question is

Q. what is the problem ?

Q. did I configure something wrong?

Q. how can I fix it based on this architecture ?

please advise for me

thank you !

Comment: If you use alb, why your error shows that you use ec2 url (not alb one): ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com?

Comment: thank you for your advice !
hmm... for the convenience I routed backend into public subnet to network with outside internet for a while 
and the question pretty much I have to edit 

I'm sorry 
my point is 
for the convience in working on deployment 
I put backend ec2 which supposed to be in private subnet and routed in public subnet for a while without architecture

but I have to route back to this formalized architecture 

so I routed my backend ec2 server as I said above 

and then this error occurred

Comment: So if everything is in public subnet, does it work if you access the app directly, without alb?

Comment: yes it works by now !
but it is for the working convience 
but I should adhere the architecture 
so private frontend and private backend are applied then it does not work